# ORM filter has no results

Tags: django, forms, view, filter, orm

I have a view:

```
def PeopleView(request):
    ...
    parameters = copy.deepcopy(request.GET)
    for parameter in request.GET:
        if not request.GET.get(parameter):
            del parameters[parameter]
    people = Person.objects.filter(**parameters)
    search_form = PersonSearchForm()
    return render(request, 'persons/people.html', {
        'people': people,
        'search_form': search_form,
        ...
    })
```

PersonSearchForm:

```
class PersonSearchForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    second_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    country = forms.CharField(required=False)
    city = forms.CharField(required=False)
    gender = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select, required=False)
    birthday = forms.DateField(required=False)
    school = forms.CharField(required=False)
    university = forms.CharField(required=False)
    profession = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

Person model has fields from PersonSearchForm with the same name. And this form is sent by user as GET request.

GET request and print of parameters variable:
[image]

However filter always has no results. What's wrong?

Comment: Dunno. What are the parameters? What does the model look like? Do you have data relating to the requested values?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added the info about PersonSearchForm. Person model has the fields with the same type and name.

Comment: Can you print `parameters` in the view and show the result?

Comment: @DanielRoseman It was added. In this example I entered only first_name and last_name fields.

Comment: @DanielRoseman If your're still interested in the problem I notify you that I wrote the solution in the question.

Comment: @AlexanderShpindler you should place your solution as an answer for your question, not as part of the question.

Comment: @GwynBleidD done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I solved the problem. The solution is a transformation of querydict parameters to dict object. It looks like:

```
...
filter_parameters = {}
for parameter in parameters:
    filter_parameters[parameter] = parameters[parameter]
people = Person.objects.filter(**filter_parameters)
...
```

And it works.